# `pandas.DataFrame.to_html()` without `table border` and `tr style`

Tags: python, html, pandas

As per title, is it possible -- and if so, how -- to produce "clean" HTML code from `pandas.DataFrame.to_html()`?

I have found that `border=...` and `justify=...` parameters control what is displayed there, but apparently no matter what value you put in there, you seems to always get them.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(3 * 4).reshape(3, 4))
df.to_html(border=0, justify='inherit')
```

which produces:

```
<table border="0" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: inherit;">
    ...
```

However, I would have been expecting that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(3 * 4).reshape(3, 4))
df.to_html(classes=None, border=None, justify=None)
```

would / should produce:

```
<table class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    ...
```

instead of:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
    ...
```

since the introduction both `border` and `style` are *appearance* rather than structure tags and should be included through the `css`.

So, is there any way to get rid of `border` from `table` and `style` from `tr` inside the `thead`?

Answer (score 4):

As you've already observed, `df.to_html(classes=None, border=None, justify=None)` disregards settings of `None`, inserting the default values regardless. There are open requests to modify this, but they are not yet in place.  As it stands, the only way to remove these hard-coded styles is to manipulate the output string, like so:

```
html = re.sub(r'<tr.*>', '<tr>', df.to_html().replace('border="1" ', ''))
```

Removing `class="dataframe"` can be accomplished the same way, but this shouldn't impact most CSS if left in place.

Comment: This would answer the question: how to modify the output of `df.to_html()` rather than how to make `df.to_html()` produce the *correct* output. I am only interested in the latter.

Comment: `df.to_html()` does not allow you to produce the correct output. The only way to remove those elements is to remove them after generating the output.

Comment: Not all questions have an answer we like :-)

Comment: @norok2 opened an according issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22692

Comment: (pandas  0.23.4) - Passing `border='0'` into the `to_html()` function will remove the border(s) successfully.

Comment: No, it will not remove the attribute, only set it to 0. As style attributes in the tag has priority, it is still not possible to set the border with css.